# Shopify AJAX form to third-party service

Tags: forms, api, shopify, shopify-app

I'm trying to build an AJAX MailChimp form in Shopify that will POST form data via the MailChimp API. Whilst being aware of Shopify Private Apps I'm unsure on how to configure them or even if this is the correct route to go down.

I come from a WordPress background where this is extremely simple with cURL requests - hoping for a similar solution.

Comment: Embed your MailChimp form into Shopify. Why do you need an ajax form? This will lead to security issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a Mailchimp signup form, they have a JSONP endpoint you can use. No apps required.

Mailchimp form action URLs look like this:

`https://name.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=dcabf4ea1e6340c0f1c34b0b6&id=ba610251dc`

For the JSONP endpoint, you just change `post` to `post-json`:

`https://name.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=dcabf4ea1e6340c0f1c34b0b6&id=ba610251dc`

Here's a jQuery snippet that demonstrates how you can progressively enhance a Mailchimp form with AJAX:

```js
$('[data-mailchimp-form]').on('submit', function(event) {
  var $form = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    url: $form.attr('action').replace('/subscribe/post', '/subscribe/post-json'),
    data: $form.serialize(),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'c',
    success: function() {
      // Show a success message.
    },
    error: function() {
      // Show an error message.
    },
    complete: function() {
      $form.append('<p>AJAX response received.</p>');
    }
  });

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://name.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=dcabf4ea1e6340c0f1c34b0b6&id=ba610251dc" method="POST" data-mailchimp-form>
  <input name="EMAIL" placeholder="email" value="test@example.com">
  <!-- Include the other fields copied with the Mailchimp form code -->
  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```